# TextView doesn't lose focus when the keyboard is dismissed

Tags: android, textview, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

This behavior occurs only on `Android` devices

```
<TextView [(ngModel)]="textData" updateTextTrigger="focusLost" (ngModelChange)="updateText()"></TextView>
```

Since I use the `updateTextTrigger` as `focusLost`, the model doesn't update since the `TextView` always stays focused unit we switch the focus to another element, which I can't do since that is the only input element at the page.

Is this an expected behavior on `Android` devices and how to handle this??

or

Is this an issue with the `NativeScript` and should be created as an issue??

Comment: Why use `focusLost` then?

Comment: @EddyVerbruggen I save the `textData` whenever the user finishes typing the content and AFAIK implementing a debounce would require me to write a wrapper around this component and it'll also hit the backend more frequently than this approach

Comment: The debounce could be a `pipe`, I've done that in the past. If you want I can paste the code here as the answer.

Comment: Using `pipe` for debounce is interesting and would love to look at the code.
Here is a minimal sample code if you would like to know what exactly I'm expecting [TextViewBlur.zip](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/files/1037851/TextViewBlur.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a slightly adjusted version of the debounce pipe shown here: https://github.com/numsu/angular2-debounce/blob/master/src/debounce.directive.ts

The code in the link above updates the model as well, which I didn't need. So pick your poison. My code is:

```
import { Input, Output } from "@angular/core";
import { EventEmitter, ElementRef, OnInit, Directive } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Directive({
  selector: '[debounce]'
})
export class DebounceDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() debounceDelay: number = 700;
  @Input() debounceFromEvent: string = "tap";
  @Output() debounceFunction: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const eventStream = Observable
        .fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, this.debounceFromEvent)
        .debounceTime(this.debounceDelay);

    eventStream.subscribe(input => this.debounceFunction.emit(input));
  }
}
```

And you can use it as this on a `Label` or whatever input you fancy:

```
<Label debounce debounceDelay="700" (debounceFunction)="saveChanges()" (tap)="updateStock(selectedArticle.article, 1)" text="Update"></Label>
```

Comment: Thank you I could use this for other scenarios as well but I wish we had something like `ngModelOptions` in `Angular2` that would make life easy

Comment: The `TextView` doesn't seem to fire `keyup` or `propertyChange` events. Which event should I use?

Comment: Give `textChange` a shot

Comment: Using `textChange` works. But still the `TextView` thats always focused  doesn't look so good. Should find a way to remove its focus when the keyboard closes.